# Add two tables in one UIScrollView in single viewcontroller in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

My first table having static data and in second table, I am adding data programmatically.
I have set the scroll view's content size sum of both table height, still its not working.
Its shows me both table separate scroll in appropriate table in iPhone.

in .xib i have taken scroll view and it contain two UITableView.

```
 long int tbl1_height=([firstItemsArray count]*54)+280;
 long int tbl2_height=([arr_MainMorningTrackList1 count]*54);
 [self.tbl_1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, tbl1_height)];
[self.tbl_2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tbl1_height, 320, tbl2_height)]; 
long int scrollHeight=tbl1_height+tbl2_height; 
self.scroll_mainView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,scrollHeight+60); 
[self.tbl_2 reloadData];
```

thanks for comments

Comment: Can you show the code what you have tried?

Comment: FYI: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`

Comment: Share what have you tried before

Comment: in .xib i have taken scroll view and it contain two UITableView.         long int tbl1_height=([firstItemsArray count]*54)+280;   
        long int tbl2_height=([arr_MainMorningTrackList1 count]*54);
        [self.tbl_1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, tbl1_height)];
        [self.tbl_2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tbl1_height, 320, tbl2_height)];
        long int scrollHeight=tbl1_height+tbl2_height; 
        self.scroll_mainView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,scrollHeight+60);
        [self.tbl_2 reloadData];    thanks for comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and trying the code I found the solution that I just forgot to **remove** the checkmark of `autolayout` of `UITableView`  in our .xib file.